# Filter pandas dataframe in python3 depending on the value of a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = {'c': ['A','B','C','D'],
      'x': [[1,2,3],[2],[1,3],[1,2,5]]}
```

And I want to create another dataframe that contains only the rows that have a certain value contained in the lists of x. For example, if I only want the ones that contain a 3, to get something like:

```
df2 = {'c': ['A','C'],
       'x': [[1,2,3],[1,3]]}
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
df2 = df[(3 in df.x.tolist())]
```

But I am getting a

```
KeyError: False
```

exception. Any suggestion/idea? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df[df.x.apply(lambda x: 3 in x)]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   c          x
0  A  [1, 2, 3]
2  C     [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code would help you

To create the Correct dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['A','B','C','D'],
      'x': [[1,2,3],[2],[1,3],[1,2,5]]})
```

To filter the rows which contains 3

```
df[df.x.apply(lambda x: 3 in x)==True]
```

Output:

```
   c    x
0  A   [1, 2, 3]
2  C   [1, 3]
```